# Java to Kotlin conversion

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

Here is a Piece of code in java.

```
Private ImageView[] = dots;
dots = new ImageView[int]; // Int Will be the size of ImageView
```

How can i convert this in kotlin.

I Tried,

```
lateinit var dots: ArrayList<ImageView>
```

But this does not give me the size.

Comment: Your Java code is not valid Java code, so we don't exactly know how to translate it. But you probably want something like `private val dots = arrayOfNulls<ImageView>(20);` An array and an ArrayList are not the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can initialize list like this:

```
val initialSize = 5
var dots = ArrayList<ImageView>(initialSize)
```

`dots` is a **Mutable**, **No Fixed Size** list of elements.

You can change elements at specific indexes and add new elements, e.g.:

```
dots[1] = ImageView()
dots.add(ImageView())
```

Also there are other ways to create **arrays** and **lists** in Kotlin:

```
// Arrays
var myArray = Array<Int>(5) { 0 }   // Mutable, Fixed Size, all elements initialized with 0
var myArray1 = arrayOf(10, 20, 30)  // Mutable, Fixed Size
var myArray2 = arrayOfNulls<Int>(5) // Mutable, Fixed Size, all elements initialized with null
var myArray3 = emptyArray<String>() // Mutable, Fixed Size

// Lists
val immutableList: List<Int> = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2) // Immutable, Fixed Size
val mutableList1 = arrayListOf<String>() // Mutable, No Fixed Size
var mutableList2 = ArrayList<Double>()   // Mutable, No Fixed Size
var mutableList22 = ArrayList<Double>(10) // Mutable, No Fixed Size
var mutableList3 = arrayListOf(*myArray1) // Mutable, No Fixed Size
val mutableList: MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf(5, 4, 3, 2, 1) // Mutable, No Fixed Size
```

Comment: dots is not an array. It's an ArrayList.

Comment: Yes, I changed `array` to `list` in my answer.